# DllMain not called in cygwin-gcc compiled program

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to build a DLL with cygwin, but from DbgView, no output is observed:

```
#include <windows.h>
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH called");
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

__attribute__((stdcall))
int _DllMainCRTStartup(int handle, int reason, void *ptr)
{ 
    return DllMain(handle, reason, ptr); 
}
```

So far it looks like DllMain is not called at all, what was wrong?

Comment: here will be useful look for binary dll, instead src code. as side note - you not need export `DllMain` and if you not use *crt* - direct set entry point to `DllMain` - no sense in this case have `_DllMainCRTStartup`

Comment: @RbMm https://easyupload.io/p330t2

Comment: this is *cygwin* specific question. how is it work. the `_DllMainCRTStartup` is ignored at all. real entry point of your dll is `_cygwin_dll_entry` - it called your `DllMain` only in case `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`, `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` and `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. but not in case `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. i dont know *cygwin* and can not say why. if you build for windows - better use *msvc* environment

Comment: @RbMm _cygwin_dll_entry worked, you may add an answer below

Comment: @RbMm Weird, I tried to compile another program, _cygwin_dll_entry is redefined this time

Comment: i don't familiar with *cygwin* environment . i use only *msvc* (cl.exe, link.exe, etc)